# Error when follow Zk essential tutorial

Tags: eclipse, zk

I am very new in ZKoss framework. I Follow ZK essential tutorial and in stuck in chapter4. The Error is when I created Package / class for SidebarChapter4Controller . There're lines :  import org.zkoss.essentials.services.SidebarPage and
import org.zkoss.essentials.services.SidebarPageConfig; it gives error. I can't find where  SidebarPage  and SidebarPageConfig and what the error is all about.

Please Help.

Thanks & Regards,

Dian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment but adding the error message might be useful.

Are you looking for these files?
[SidebarPage.java](https://github.com/zkoss/zkessentials/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zkoss/essentials/services/SidebarPage.java)
[SidebarPageConfig.java](https://github.com/zkoss/zkessentials/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zkoss/essentials/services/SidebarPageConfig.java)

Comment: Hi Col, thanks. I think so, but where should I put this file ? I am sorry I am very new in ZK.

Comment: Have you maintained the **essentials** folder from the path **org.zkoss.essentials.chapter4** package? If so, create a **services** folder under the **essentials** folder and save the classes in the **services** folder. Otherwise you can save them in any package you like in your project and update your **import** statement to point to them.

Comment: Thanks Col, I got it.